# From the GCP console, can we write a GCP cloud function interacting with Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Two years ago, I made a (unique) project mixing Firebase and GCP. ESP32 sensors managed by GCP IoT Core published messages (temperature and humidity values) on a PubSub topic, also handled by GCP.
A Firebase Cloud Function was triggered by message publication on the PubSub topic.The aim of this Firebase Cloud Function was to log then store the data arriving on the topic to the Firebase Realtime Database of the project. Eventually, a web app was in charge of plotting data contained in the messages across time.

That's the big picture and the result is here: https://hello-cloud-iot-core.firebaseapp.com/

Everything worked fine for two years but a few days ago the Firebase Cloud Functions wasn't triggered anymore. Surely because it was run with Node.js 6, which went deprecated a few months ago.

As I didn't want to redeploy my function with locally installed Firebase Tools that I didn't update regularly, I chose to rewrite the Cloud Function with GCP console, choosing Node.js 10 as runtime environment.

When I deploy the code below without the red framed code, deployment is correct and logs are fine at runtime. But when I add the parts dealing with Firebase Realtime Database (red framed code below), deployment fails.

Is my syntax incorrect? Or should I add some packages in the package.json file? If yes, which versions of them?[image: GCP cloud function inline editor]

Comment: In my personal experience, when I deploy a cloud function, there should be a few lines/records in the log about that deployment. If there are any issues - they are usually reflected as errors (usually 2 or 3 lines) in the StackDriver logs. Can you describe what is there, please?

Comment: The log (reproduced just after) says there is a syntax error at line 5, but I don't know why.
Build failed: /workspace/index.js:5 export function helloPubSub(message, context) { ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token export at new Script (vm.js:83:7) at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:620:5) at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11) at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3); Error ID: d984e68f

Comment: Trying things step by step, I got this message at run time in the log: `FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing`. That's how I went to the answer I publish in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!
Here is the code for `package.json`, note the addition of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` dependencies:

```json
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.18.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

And here is the code for `index.js`, note how `admin.initializeApp()` method is more complete and how I modified syntax at line dealing with the export of the `helloPubSub` function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//admin.initializeApp();
admin.initializeApp({
    projectId: 'your-project-id',
    //credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.helloPubSub = (message, context) => {
  const messageData = Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString();
  // console.log(`DATA =  ${messageData}`);
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(messageData);
  const temperature = parsedData.temperature.toFixed(1) - 2;
  const humidity = Math.round(parsedData.humidity);
  if((temperature<-40) || (temperature>80) || (humidity <0) || (humidity > 100)) return;
  const deviceId = message.attributes.deviceId;
  const timestamp = context.timestamp
  console.log(`TEMPERATURE = ${temperature} - HUMIDITY = ${humidity} - DEVICE_ID = ${deviceId} - TIMESTAMP = ${timestamp}`);
  
  return admin.database().ref(`devices-telemetry/${deviceId}`).push({
      timestamp: timestamp,
      temperature: temperature,
      humidity: humidity
  })
}
```

Comment: If you deploy with your own populated [`FIREBASE_CONFIG`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) and [`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) environment variables, you can avoid having to pass the configuration object into `admin.initializeApp()` like you would if you deployed from the Firebase CLI.